# Resize views on click with animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation

I'm trying to make a user interface that animates when I click on it.

This is my sketch:

[image]

It starts with the mapview as small as on the left sketch. The rest is filled with a tableview. Now when I click on the map view it slides to the bottom like on the right sketch so the mapview fills the most off the screen. Ans visa versa when I click on the small Tableview.

How can I achieve this?

I thought off creating a View and then add mapview and tableview as subviews, but then I don't know how to animate that. Did some real simple animations until now.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  NSNumber isMapExpanded = 0;

  - (void) expandMap 
    {
       [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                             delay:0.2
                           options:nil
                        animations:^{
                                 if([isMapExtended integerValue] == 0)
                                 {
                                     mapview.frame = CGRectMake(mapview.frame.origin.x, mapview.frame.origin.y, mapview.frame.size.width, mapview.frame.size.height + heightTobeExpanded);
                                     tableView.frame = CGrectMake(tableView.frame.origin.x, tableView.frame.origin.y - heightTobeExpanded, tableView.frame.size.width, tableView.frame.size.height + heightTobeExpanded);
                                 }  
                                 else if([isMapExtended integerValue] == 1)
                                 {
                                     mapview.frame = CGRectMake(mapview.frame.origin.x, mapview.frame.origin.y, mapview.frame.size.width, mapview.frame.size.height - heightTobeExpanded);
                                     tableView.frame = CGrectMake(tableView.frame.origin.x, tableView.frame.origin.y + heightTobeExpanded, tableView.frame.size.width, tableView.frame.size.height - heightTobeExpanded);
                                 }     
                           }
             completion:nil];
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

something along the lines of:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                      delay:0
                    options:nil
                 animations:^{
                     map.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,newheight,320);
                     table.frame = CGrectMake(0,newheight,screenheight-newheight, 320);
                 }
                 completion:nil];
```

you can call something like that in your click method. this is just an example - you should not use hardcoded numbers in your application :)

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code:-

```
 [UIView beginAnimations:@"Expand MApview" context:nil];    
 [tblView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-50, tblView.frame.size.width,tblView.frame.size.height)];
 [mapview setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,mapview.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height-50)];
 [UIView setAnimationDelay:2];
 [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 1):

1. As you already stated, put both the map and the table in a superview.
2. On click, you may use the following :

> [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
>
> ```
>     map.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,width,newHeight); //Set the frame to be with the new map height
>     tableView.frame = CGRectMake(x,NewYCoordinate,width,height);  //Move the tableView down
> }];
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void) changeFrameBetweenMapAndTable
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                      delay:0.5
                    options:nil
                 animations:^{
                     CGRect mapRect = mapview.frame;
                         mapview.frame = tableView.frame;
                         tableView.frame = mapRect;
                 }
                 completion:nil];
}
```